# MYSQL using other tables

Tags: mysql

This query:

```
SELECT 
user_id, 
count(base_item) 
FROM items 
WHERE base_item = '202' 
group by user_id order by count(base_item)
```

Gives me this result:

[image]

which I want.
However, I also want it to exclude all user `id`s in the `users` table with a `rank` of 5 or greater. as shown here

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your `where` clause this way:

```
WHERE base_item = '202' AND user_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM users WHERE rank > 5)
```

The portion in parentheses is called a subquery.  The result set of the subquery contains the id of all users with a rank greater than 5.  The addition to the `where` clause excludes all users in that result set.

Comment: Good to hear.  And thanks for accepting the answer.  Upvoting it is another way to express that you found it to be a useful answer ;)  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Join with the `users` table and filter out rows with high rank

```
SELECT user_id, count(*) AS count
FROM items AS i
JOIN users AS u ON i.user_id = u.id
WHERE i.base_item = '202' 
AND u.rank <= 5
group by user_id 
order by count
```